# Write the result of a bash command in csv or xls

Tags: bash, file, csv, xls

I need to search for files in a specific directory and save the result [filename] [size] in different csv/xls columns. Please tell me how this can be done.

What I tried:
**find ./mydir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 du -ch | awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{$1=$1}1' > mycsvfile.csv**

What I got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6zrP.png)

I want to get the result in different cells of the table

enter image description here

Comment: your result is a CSV, but you are not importing it correctly in excel. on a side note, if you have `find` with `-print0` you probably have `du` with `--files0-from`. when using `xargs` for a large file list you might reach the command line size limit.

Answer (score -1):

Could you try the below code;

```
find mydir/ -type f -exec du -sh {} \; | sed 's/[[:space:]]/,/' > file.csv
```

Comment: Hi, Nitish! I tried it, but it still saved the result in column A through ",".

Comment: OP had also a grand total (`du -c`) which is lost here, and the format of the output is identical

Comment: @Kurtman Could you check [this](https://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel) link and see if this solves your problem. I feel it's more of an excel issue as I get size and file names in different columns.